# Web image search API that allows to filter by license

Tags: image, api, search, bing

I'm trying to use an image search API to get images to use on my site, however I need to be able to filter by license, so that I can actually use the images! My first thought was "hey, I'll use google's image search API!", well that has been deprecated. Bing's API is horribly documented, however I finally got it to work, only to realize they don't let you filter by license (even though they do on the live site, sigh...). Google's custom search API seems like a complete mess and only limits you to 100 queries a day for free, however they DO allow you to filter by license.

Does anyone have any good ideas on what to use? It looks like Google Custom Search currently looks like the only one that will allow me to filter by license - but the API seems like it's trying to be a lot of things that it isn't and seems more for integrating a a custom search bar into the frontend of a site.

Answer (score 1):

you can try flickr's api, which allows you to filter by license